# Why does curl say all websites with http are available?

Tags: php, http, curl

I am using a `cURL` script to check if a website is available.

It does not work properly though; according to it, all URL's that have `http://` are available. Why does this do this?

Here is my code:

```
function isDomainAvailible($domain)
{
    //check, if a valid url is provided
    if(!filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //initialize curl
    $curlInit = curl_init($domain);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    //get answer
    $response = curl_exec($curlInit);

    curl_close($curlInit);

    if ($response) return true;

    return false;
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do a `var_dump($response);` on the line after you assign it from the `curl_exec()` call. You can also use `curl_error()` to debug further.

Comment: what you have response and what is your domain?

Comment: Could you give an example of a parameter/result that is actually wrong?

Comment: Anything with http:// is correct, even this: http://www.xsgjlcdgjklxsdgjksdflk.com

Comment: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html Array ( [url] => http://www.xsgjlcdgjklxsdgjksdflk.com [content_type] => text/html [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 142 [request_size] => 70 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.198682 [namelookup_time] => 2.1E-5 [connect_time] => 0.098941 [pretransfer_time] => 0.098968 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 0 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 0.198661 [redirect_time] => 0 )

Comment: Your `http://www.xsgjlcdgjklxsdgjksdflk.com/` example returns `false` for me with the code you have provided.

Comment: That's weird... It returns true for me

Comment: @Jack This is my website: http://wreview.comlu.com/review could you try entering a wrong url and tell me what message you get? (success or error)

Comment: If you're a home user, the DNS of some ISPs return "ok" pointing to a failure page instead of a proper DNS error, which will confuse your code.

Comment: your code returning false for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the code, it seems that you're either behind a transparent web proxy or being served by a non-standard name server;

A transparent proxy will make a request on your behalf and return its response. If that's the case, it seems that in the case of a non-existent location it will still return a 200 status code.

A non-standard name server may return the IP address of a web server that hosts a custom landing page (think of "domain for sale") instead of returning a lookup error.

You can request cURL to provide more debugging information by setting the appropriate option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
```

Lastly, check the returned body to see what is being returned. It should be obvious from there which of the above scenarios applies here.

Comment: Okay you're right, it's just for me then. How could I fix it though? I don't want users of my website who have their network set up like me to be able to break my website.

Comment: Nobody can break your site by changing *their* DNS configuration, but you should definitely look into fixing your own setup :) check with your hosting provider.

Comment: The point is that the cURL checks if an user entered url is valid, and would enter it into the database if it is. This would make false entries into the database if for them it says that it's right? Also I cannot change my network settings - it's my college wifi I think.

Comment: @SimonH Whichever the case, you should check with your hosting provider to find out which of the above claims is true and how they can fix it.

Comment: @SimonH Wait, you're running a server off a school Wifi network?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I got you wrong! I am using a free hosting service, so that's probably the problem. I thought it differed for each user, I'm sorry!

Answer (score 0):

try with `curl_getinfo()` for getting curl exec info

```
//get answer
$response = curl_exec($curlInit);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
print_r(curl_getinfo($curlInit));
$info = curl_getinfo($curlInit);
if ($info['http_code'] == '200')
  return true;
else 
  retrun 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curlInit);
```

also use ssl verifypeer some of sites using ssl

```
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Also domain must be like :- http://www.example.com (with http://)
If you specify URL without protocol:// prefix, curl will attempt to guess what protocol you might want. It will then default to HTTP but try other protocols based on often-used host name prefixes. For example, for host names starting with "ftp." curl will assume you want to speak FTP. 
 read :- http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

for more info read the manual :- http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: i am giving suggestion for check